# How can I delete emojis and zalgo in username?

Tags: discord.js

How can I delete the characters except the letters between a and z in the user name after logging into the server?

[image: desired effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen on a member join then change their nick:

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.setNickname(member.user.username.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, ""));
});
```